# ADO Recordset Decimal value issue

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I have code similar to

```
Dim A, B, C
Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strSql = "Exec [dbo].[some_sp] IND"
rs.open strSql,CN,3,3

Do While Not rs.EOF

'these columns are returned as decimal(10,2) format
A = rs("col1")
B = rs("col2")

rs.MoveNext
Loop

C = A + B 'i get type mismatch error here
```

And I used response.write to check values for A, B 
they are in integer format and not decimal

Do i have to format recordset again to set decimal values?
And what could be possible problem for type mismatch as all values are integer (even if they are decimal) ?

Comment: Answer:
Used A = CDbl(rs("col1"))
B = CDbl(rs("col2"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables in ASP/VBScript are just variant types so you may need to convert the values explicitly.

```
C = CDbl(A) + CDbl(B)
```

However, my guess would be that one of your rows does not have a numeric value for col1 or col2.  Do you know what the values of those are when you get the type mismatch error?

Comment: Also, can the procedure ever return a NULL?

Comment: yes i did response.write for all those values here is the result
73, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 6

I want them to be decimal before adding but they are in integer

Comment: i figured it out. I used CDbl and it is working (Cdec will not work)

Comment: Ah yeah that doesn't work in VBScript.  I'll update my answer with your findings.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I found everything to the right of the decimal was being lost, essentially returning an integer. This is in Access 2007 with ADO 2.8, calling SQL on a DB2/400 v7r3 server.

I tried using `VBA.CDbl()` and `CDec()`, but neither of them worked. Then reading this thread inspried me to try the conversion on the server first, so I `CAST` the number to `REAL`, which is 32 bits (equivalent to `Single` in VBA), and this worked.

This:

```
SELECT (IYONHA / WXUNIT) AS VIPCASES
FROM   WINEX
```

...became this:

```
SELECT CAST(IYONHA / WXUNIT AS REAL) AS VIPCASES
FROM   WINEX
```

...and then to round the decimals down to two places became this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(IYONHA / WXUNIT AS NUMERIC(5,2)) AS REAL) AS VIPCASES
FROM   WINEX
```