# How to add up total cost

Tags: asp-classic

I like to create a total cost column at the end. This field only adds up the total of 2 fields (aFees + fFees). For example, when 
I enter $100 in aFees box, the total box should show $100. If I enter $50 in fFees box, then the total should show $150.

However, it didn't work.

Here is a block of code. Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

```
Response.Write "      <tr>"
Response.Write "        <td>Airplane Fees:</td>"
Response.Write "    <td><input type=""text"" name=""aFees"" size=24  value=""$" & rsData("aFees") & """></td>"
Response.Write "      <tr>"
Response.Write "        <td width=150>Food Fees: </td>"
Response.Write "    <td><input type=""text"" name=""fFees"" size=24 value=""$" & rsData("fFees") & """></td>"
Response.Write "      </tr>"
 Response.Write "      <tr>"
Response.Write "        <td>TOTAL: </td>"

Dim totalCost, aFees, fFees, cost
While Not rsData.EOF
totalCost = trim(rsData.Fields("aFees"))+trim(rsData.Fields("fFees"))
cost = cost + totalCost
Wend

Response.Write "    <td><input type=""text"" name=""cost"" size=24 value=""$" & rsData("cost") & """></td>"
Response.Write "      </tr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to remember to my class asp days :)  I believe the rsData object is not strong typed, so it tends to default to string.  Try converting both to integers then add

```
cint(trim(rsData.Fields("aFees"))) + cint(trim(rsData.Fields("fFees")))
```

cint() converts them to integers - assuming it's a valid integer.  you should probably add some error handling in case they are blank, null or non-numeric.

Comment: that's what I meant above that you should have some error handling for the cInt() (I forget if classic asp is case-sensitive or not, if it is, use cap "I" = cInt())  if rsData.Fields("aFees") or rsData.Fields("fFees") is null, it will error.  Are you sure both of these are returning integers or decimals. also, I just noticed you said you were adding monetary values, so they are probably have decimals right?  if so, you might have to use cDec() which converts them to decimals values instead of int, which would round to the nearest whole number.

Comment: i looked up cdec() and this came up - might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971251/ado-recordset-decimal-value-issue